# Superconducting charge qubit and Cooper pairs

Tags: experimental-realization

In the superconducting charge qubit implementation of the qubit what I've understood is that we read a 1 if a Cooper pair has gone through the Josephson Junction into the "island" and we read a 0 if there is no Cooper pair. How come it's only possible that one Cooper pair passes the Josephson Junction? I don't really understand how this is a binary system as there seems to be more than two possibilities when one measures the system.

Comment: are you asking about dual rail encoding? if you are then this has some details : https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.08737

Comment: No sorry, I'm just asking how a superconducting charge qubit actually works.